# IONIC error TS2488: Type 'Object' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

```
getData() {
this.http.get(`https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/${this.country}/status/confirmed?from=2020-04-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z`).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Res: ', res);

  this.chartData[0].data = [];
  this.chartLabels = [];

  for (let entry of res) {
    // splitting Date from Date and Time that was provided from dataset
    this.chartLabels.push(entry.Date.split('T')[0]);
    this.chartData[0].data.push(entry['Cases']);
  }
  console.log('data: ', this.chartData);
});
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsMb.png)

Got this function to call data from an API about 2 days ago, but when I tried to "ionic serve" the project again today, I ran into a compiling error. This error came up before, but I seeked help and one of my friend told me it's a TS' side error that can be ignored.

The error seems to come from the "res" Object. I am a new coder so a simple explanation would be very helpful!

I am very confused, please do ask if any more information is needed.

Thank you!

- new stackoverflow user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getData() {
this.http.get(`https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/${this.country}/status/confirmed?from=2020-04-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-05-01T00:00:00Z`).subscribe((res:any) => 
{
  console.log('Res: ', res);

  this.chartData[0].data = [];
  this.chartLabels = [];

  for (let entry of res) {
    // splitting Date from Date and Time that was provided from dataset
    this.chartLabels.push(entry.Date.split('T')[0]);
    this.chartData[0].data.push(entry['Cases']);
  }
  console.log('data: ', this.chartData);
});
}
```

Changed line 2 from ".subscribe(res => {"
to 
".subscribe((res:any) => {" and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your **respose object** check that object

```
//sample object and it goes iterator
let res = [1,2,3,4,4];

  for (let entry of res) {
    console.log('data: ', entry);
  }
```

Comment: Might I know where to add the line:

let res = [1,2,3,4,4];

Also, what data will be put into the []? Still a little confused on what a Symbol.iterator is meant for.